# partman-auto/expert_recipe with swap calculation during preseed

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, swap, preseed

I can't find any useful information regarding swap calculation for partman and I've also tried partitioning with the below schema with no success, hopefully, you may be able to help me here.

I'm using preseed for disk partitioning, and while doing so I want the swap partition to be x1.5 of the RAM, but not more than 12GB.

example use-case: I've machines with 6GB of RAM and machines with 192GB.
having said that, for the machine with the 6GB

I want 9GB swap partition(x1.5), but for the 192GB I don't want a 288GB swap partition, of course, the idea is that no matter how much
physical RAM the machine has above 12G it will create
a maximum of a 12GB swap partition.

I hope partman can offer this or I'll need to create some dynamic 
script during early_command before partitioning.

## Partition Schema

```
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string \
   boot-root :: \
      300 2048 2048 ext4 method{ format } \
      $primary{ } $bootable{ } \
      format{ } use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
      mountpoint{ /boot } \
      . \
      150% 150% 12288 linux-swap method{ swap } \
      format{ } $lvmok{ } lv_name{ swap } \
      . \
      61440 61440 61440 ext4 method{ lvm } \
      $lvmok{ } mountpoint{ / } lv_name{ root } \
      format{ } use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
      options/relatime{ relatime } \
      . \
      51200 51200 51200 ext4 method{ lvm } \
      $lvmok{ } mountpoint{ /tmp } lv_name{ tmp } \
      format{ } use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
      options/relatime{ relatime } \
      options/nodev{ nodev } options/nosuid{ nosuid } \
      . \
      1 1000 10000000000 ext4 method{ lvm } \
      $lvmok{ } mountpoint{ /localdrive } lv_name{ localdrive } \
      format{ } use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
      options/usrquota{ usrquota } options/grpquota{ grpquota } \
      options/user_xattr{ user_xattr } options/acl{ acl } \
      options/nodev{ nodev } options/relatime{ relatime } \
      .
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay i've configured it during early_command, seems like my only option.

Here is the recipe that worked for me:

```
# PartMan LVM Method
 # first drive is selected and selected only.
 # 1. /boot partition size 2G.
 # 2. swap will be x1.5 of the pysical RAM but not more then 12G.
 # 3. / - root is fixed to 60G.
 # 4. /tmp fixed to 50G.
 # 6. /localdrive will take all the unallocated space.

d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-auto/purge_lvm_from_device boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string vg
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm_span boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/alignment string optimal
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

# These commands will run immediately before the partitioner starts.
d-i partman/early_command string \
    debconf-set partman-auto/disk "$(list-devices disk | head -n1)"; \
    debconf-set grub-installer/bootdev "$(list-devices disk | head -n1)"; \
    TMEM=$(($(sed -n 's/^MemTotal: \+\([0-9]*\) kB/\1/p' /proc/meminfo) / 1024)); \
    DSWAP=$(expr $TMEM \* 150 \/ 100); \
     if [ "${DSWAP}" -gt "12288" ]; then \
         DSWAP=12288; \
     fi; \
    debconf-set partman-auto/expert_recipe "boot-root :: \
        300 2048 2048 ext4 method{ format } \
        \$primary{ } \$bootable{ } \
        format{ } use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
        mountpoint{ /boot } \
        . \
        ${DSWAP} ${DSWAP} ${DSWAP} linux-swap method{ swap } \
        format{ } \$lvmok{ } lv_name{ swap } \
        . \
        61440 61440 61440 ext4 method{ lvm } \
        \$lvmok{ } mountpoint{ / } lv_name{ root } \
        format{ } use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
        options/relatime{ relatime } \
        . \
        51200 51200 51200 ext4 method{ lvm } \
        \$lvmok{ } mountpoint{ /tmp } lv_name{ tmp } \
        format{ } use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
        options/relatime{ relatime } \
        options/nodev{ nodev } options/nosuid{ nosuid } \
        . \
        1 1000 10000000000 ext4 method{ lvm } \
        \$lvmok{ } mountpoint{ /localdrive } lv_name{ localdrive } \
        format{ } use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
        options/usrquota{ usrquota } options/grpquota{ grpquota } \
        options/user_xattr{ user_xattr } options/acl{ acl } \
        options/nodev{ nodev } options/relatime{ relatime } \
        .";
```